# PHP & MySQL: Group query results and take averages

Tags: php, mysql, database

I have data in the following format:

```
1/1/2017   55
1/3/2017   23
1/3/2017   87
1/3/2017   45
1/4/2017   77
1/4/2017   90
1/4/2017   34
```

What is the fasted and most efficient way to query the database and output the average value for each date?

Comment: First store dates as dates. Then get back to us

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your question is missing a lot of information and shows little or no effort in solving the problem.

Regardless, you can use a SQL query like this to achieve the results you want:

```
SELECT date_col, AVG(number_col) as average FROM table_name GROUP BY date_col
```

Comment: I would add date_col to the select so they can see what date the averages correspond to.

Comment: And set an good alias for the average-column so it's easier to access. Maybe like this: `SELECT date, AVG(value) AS average FROM table_name GROUP BY date`

Answer (score -1):

Try this

```
SELECT avg(value_field) FROM `table_name` group by date _field
```

Comment: why table name is mentioned as `stck` ?

Comment: Moreover for group by you dont need paranthesis ()

Comment: Actually I use stk as table name. Sorry I will replace with table_name